# TraceFlag 1118 for TempDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are many advantages of enabling trace flag 1118 ( as a service startup paramter) for TempDB to reduce contention related to mixed extent allocation even it case of SQL 2008/R2 or SQL 2012. Why in the world it is disabled out of the box in a default SQL server configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Misconceptions around TF 1118](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-around-TF-1118.aspx). Read the paragraph about *Why is the trace flag not required so much in 2005 and 2008?*. Also consider that there are plenty of workloads that make little or no use of temp tables (eg. most well designed OLTP workloads) and some of those workloads could potentially suffer from extend allocations in tempdb.

Answer (score 3):

> Use TF-1118. Under this trace flag SQL Server allocates full extents
>   to each tempdb object, thereby eliminating the contention on SGAM
>   page. **This is done at the expense of some waste of disk space in
>   tempdb.** This trace flag has been available since SQL Server 2000. With
>   improvements in tempdb object caching in SQL Server 2005, there should
>   be significantly less contention in allocation structures. If you see
>   contention in SGAM pages, you may want to use this trace flag. Cached
>   tempdb objects may not always be available. For example, cached tempdb
>   objects are destroyed when the query plan with which they are
>   associated is recompiled or removed from the procedure cache.

So it takes more space which can hurt certain workloads.

Comment: Creating one `tempdb` per core on the same volume can be counter productive as demonstrated in [SQLWebcast1Part2of3.wmv](http://www.sqlworkshops.com/) (About 2 minutes in)

Comment: I actually agree and I changed my mind. I removed my recommendation. Recommendations should be backed by evidence, not just by guessing.